# AngularJs / Propagating efficiently WebSockets events/messages to various controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, websocket

Using AngularJs, I wrote a `factory` aiming to handle a WebSocket connection.
Here's its code:

```
.factory('WebSocketConnection', function () {
        var service = {};
        service.callbacks = [];
        service.connect = function() {
            if(service.ws) 
              return;
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/ws");
            ws.onmessage = function (message) {
                angular.forEach(service.callbacks, function(callback){
                    callback(message);
                });
            };
            service.ws = ws;
        };

        service.send = function(message) {
            service.ws.send(message);
        };

        service.subscribe = function(callback) {
          service.callbacks.push(callback);
        };
        return service;
});
```

Basically, it allows each Angular components like `controller` or `factory`/`service` to register a specific callback, in order to handle messages; hence the callbacks array.
Here's the interesting excerpt of a listening `controller`:

```
WebSocketConnection.subscribe(function (message) {  
      $scope.$apply(function () {
         var data = angular.fromJson(message.data);
         $scope.notifications.push(data);
      });
});
```

So the callbacks array would contain this function.

But...what if I won't need this controller any more at some time? (for instance when I navigate to other page based on another controller)
I would be forced to delete the callback item (this function) from the array each time usage of the  controller is left, to avoid useless, maybe conflicting, process of this callback as long as any further messages are handled.
Not handy...

I thought about a way to broadcast event from the `$rootScope` from the factory, so that a specific controller doesn't have to manage his listeners/subscriptions itself.
But I don't want to involve all the scope tree, including all scopes that are not concerned.

What would be a good practice?

Note: I need to achieve a relation 1-N where 1 is the WebSocket handler (factory) and N, any parallel alive Angular components, each needing to listen to messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @calebboyd who made remind me the existence of the `$scope`'s `destroy` event, I think I have found a good way to achieve my requirement.

A semi-automatic way to let the controller unsubscribe itself would be to add this piece of code:

```
$scope.$on("$destroy",function() {
  WebSocketConnection.unsubscribe($scope.$id);      
});
```

Subscribing mechanism would look like this:

```
WebSocketConnection.subscribe($scope.$id, function (message) {   //note the $scope.$id parameter
      $scope.$apply(function () {
         var data = angular.fromJson(message.data);
         $scope.notifications.push(data);
      });
});
```

Therefore, the full factory code would be:

```
.factory('WebSocketConnection', function () {
        var service = {};
        service.callbacks = {}; //note the object declaration, not Array
        service.connect = function() {
            if(service.ws) 
              return;
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/ws");
            ws.onmessage = function (message) {
                angular.forEach(service.callbacks, function(callback){
                    callback(message);
                });
            };
            service.ws = ws;
        };

        service.send = function(message) {
            service.ws.send(message);
        };

        service.subscribe = function(concernedScopeId, callback) {
          service.callbacks[concernedScopeId] = callback;
        };

        service.unsubscribe = function(concernedScopeId) {
          delete service.callbacks[concernedScopeId];
        };

        return service;
});
```

And that does the trick: each useless callback acting as listener can then be detected and deleted.

Comment: When do we connect to socket in our application? And when do we disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest maintaining your model in a service or factory object. This would enable you to interact with the data as it exists there and not be dependent on the state of your application (what controllers exist) when a message is recieved. It can also allow you to enforce the concept of:

> $scope ***has*** model instead of $scope ***as*** model

That might look something like this:

```
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
        Service.notifications.push(event.data);
    }
}
```

and

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Service', 
function($scope, Service) {
    $scope.notifications = Service.notifications; //references are ===
}])
```

To enable flexibility you can use data contained in the message to determine what injectable/methods need to be updated, then use the `$injector`.

Comment: But with your presented solution, `Service` (being by definition a singleton) would then act as a full store of notifications (what about a wasted memory?). An event-oriented solution would act as a "Consume or pass but I won't store them", rather than a "I have stored them, if you want them, call me". What do you think?

Comment: If memory is a concern you may do something like `$scope.$on("$destroy",function(){$scope.notifications.length = 0})`
That is provided that data isn't used/needed anywhere else

Comment: Oh I forgot the existence of the `destroy`event :) What if I keep my existing solution and just index my array of callbacks with the `$scope.$id`. This would allow me to retrieve and delete the right callback item each time its corresponding controller's `$scope` is destroyed. Signature would become: `service.subscribe = function(concernedScopeId, callback) {`. With such a solution, I wouldn't have to carry about the notifications that 'aren't needed elsewhere' (as you wrote) before cleaning the place. What do you think? (second edition ;))  Thanks

Comment: Sure! that sounds like a more complete pub/sub (/unsub) solution

Comment: All the secret resides in the `destroy` event :) Thanks a lot!